# Get width and height of embed image in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, size, embed

I have the follow declaration :

```
[Embed(source="i/6.png")]
private var img6 : Class;
```

- How can i determine "img6" width and height ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine size of embed image only on instantiation. Something like:

```
<s:BitmapImage source="{img6}" complete="completeHandler(event)" />
…
private function completeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    var image:BitmapImage = BitmapImage(event.currentTarget);
    trace (image.sourceWidth);
    trace (image.sourceHeight);
}
```